# Timing issue with ActionCable, Capybara Webkit, and Capybara Session#window

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, functional-testing, capybara-webkit

I have a Rails 5 app that uses ActionCable to register 'guest' appearances. When you visit the site, you're prompted for your name. Once entered, your appearance is broadcast to all subscribers. When you exit your window, or 'disappear', you are shown to have left. It works great; the problem I have is testing disappearances - it passes only about half the time.

Here's the relevant test:

```
RSpec.feature "Appearances", type: :feature, js: true do
  let(:picard) { 'Picard' }
  let(:riker) { 'Riker' }

scenario "A guest disappears" do
  create_guest picard
  new_window = within_new_incognito_window do
    visit '/'
    expect(page).to have_content picard
    create_guest riker
  end  
  new_window.close
  expect(page).to_not have_content riker
end
```

And the helpers:

```
module GuestHelpers
  def within_new_incognito_window
    new_window = open_new_window
    within_window new_window do
      Capybara.current_session.driver.clear_cookies
      yield
    end
    new_window
  end

  def create_guest(name)
    within('#new_guest') do
      fill_in('guest[name]', with: name)
    end
    click_on("Go")
    expect(page).to have_content name
  end
end
```

I've tried setting the default_max_wait_time to 100, I've tried inserting sleep(10) around closing the window, and I've tried ditching the helpers and just doing it procedurally. I think it's a timing issue around closing the window - am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What error are you getting, and how long after closing the window does the guests name disappear from the original window?  Also, are you sure all mentions of "Riker"  disappear from the original window,  there isn't a message like "Riker has logged off" or anything like that on the page?

Comment: No error, just a failing test: `expected not to find text "Riker" in "ActionChat Guests Picard Riker Destroy All Guests Send"`

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Sorry, tried to edit previous comment with more information. There is no flash message or confirmation, the panel with "Riker" in it should disappear within a few moments. In case I messed up the window management logic, I made a video of the desired behavior: https://youtu.be/-itB65gdmEw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test features using RSpec which require ActiveJobs to run I find the following useful - install `rspec-activejob`, set `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :test` in your test.rb and then put the following file in your spec/support directory

```
require 'rspec/active_job'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include(RSpec::ActiveJob)

  # clean out the queue after each spec
  config.after(:each) do
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.enqueued_jobs = []
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.performed_jobs = []
  end

  config.around :each, perform_enqueued: true do |example|
    @old_perform_enqueued_jobs = ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_jobs
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_jobs = true
    example.run
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_jobs = @old_perform_enqueued_jobs
  end

  config.around :each, peform_enququed_at: true do |example|
    @old_perform_enqueued_at_jobs = ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_at_jobs
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_at_jobs = true
    example.run
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_at_jobs = @old_perform_enqueued_at_jobs
  end
end
```

which will configure different metadata you can use per test to specify whether or not you want the active jobs created to be executed during your test.

```
scenario "does something that needs job to run", perform_enqueued: true do
   ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks @ThomasWalpole, this is great.

Answer (score 0):

I got the test passing consistently by refactoring the disappearing broadcast out of an ActiveJob worker and into the AppearancesChannel. I didn't configure the test environment to use ActiveJob!

Comment: If you set `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :test` in your test.rb then you can tag scenarios where you want jobs to run with some metadata (in the example below perform_enqueued: true and setup an around block to turn on performing of the jobs - something like 
`config.around :each, perform_enqueued: true do |example|
    @old_perform_enqueued_jobs = ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_jobs
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_jobs = true
    example.run
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_jobs = @old_perform_enqueued_jobs
  end`

Comment: I added the full config I use for tests that need activejob as an answer for you.